# How to use avconv filters after encoding?

Tags: libav

I have this avconv command:

```
avconv -i file -s [new size options] -vf "[filters]" /root/converted/1.mp4
```

Avconv uses the `-vf` filters before the `-s` scaling, but I need one avconv command to:

1. Resize video first
2. Use filters second

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a chain of filters, where you add a scale filter in the first part of the filter. E.g.:

```
avconv -i file -vf "scale=w=1920h=1080, [filter B], [filter C]" /root/converted/1.mp4
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's the right avconv method. FFmpeg uses `scale=1920x1080`, so I changed that in my answer.